# Slokas about discipline in Mahabaratha

Tags: mahabharata, shloka, reference-request

It is well known that many people in Mahabaratha such as Bhishma, Drona, Arjuna, Duryodhana, Karna, Abhimanyu etc., are experts in certain fields.

In order to gain such expertise, there should be a lot of discipline. **Is there any sloka in Mahabharata saying about discipline**?